# Spring Webflow: Securing An Individual Binding

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

So, I am implementing a `<binder>` in my various flow definitions in order to secure what gets bound to the model from each page in the flow. So, a `<binder>` section might look like this:

```
<binder>
    <binding property="name" />
    <binding property="departmentId" />
    <binding property="phoneNumber" />
    <binding property="qualificationOverride" />
</binder>
```

My problem is that I don't want the "qualificationOverride" to bind to the model unless the user has a specified role (ROLE_MANAGER).

Anyone have any ideas?

Jason

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is not bind it, and on submit get the value from requestParameters, then go to a decision state where you can use secured to check permission and set the value.

something like this (I haven't tested it):

```
<view-state id="view" model="model">
    <binder>
        <binding property="name" />
        <binding property="departmentId" />
        <binding property="phoneNumber" />
        <!--<binding property="qualificationOverride" />-->
    </binder>
    <transition on="submit" to="bindIfManager">
        <set name="flowScope.qualificationOverride" value="requestParameters.qualificationOverride/>
    </transition>
</view-state>

<action-state id="bindIfManager">
    <!-- you will have to implement this, basically user.getAuthorities.contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role))-->
    <evaluate expression="securityAction.isUserInRole(currentUser, 'ROLE_MANAGER')"/>
    <transition on="yes" to="finish">
        <set name="model.qualificationOverride" value="flowScope.qualificationOverride"/>
    </transition>
    <transition on="no" to="finish"/>
</action-state>
```

Comment: I tried it, but the values did not seem to be directly in the request parameters if they were not listed in the <binder>.

Comment: that's strange, I just tested it and the property was in requestParameters

Comment: you could also try with a regular input <input type="text" name="qualificationOverride" value="${model.qualificationOverride}"/> in your form